# Copy User Fields from CRM Quote to Sales Order

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to copy some user fields from the CRM Quote to the Sales Order. The CRM Quote uses a different object than the Sales Quote and there doesn't appear to be a  way to relate it back. I tried overriding the Create Sales Order to add a handler, but this didn't seem to work Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code I tried:

```
public class OpportunityMaint_Extension : PXGraphExtension<OpportunityMaint>
{
    public delegate IEnumerable CreateSalesOrderDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);

    [PXOverride]
    public virtual IEnumerable CreateSalesOrder(PXAdapter adapter, CreateSalesOrderDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        Base.RowInserting.AddHandler<SOLine>((sender, e) =>
        {
            SOLine orderLine = e.Row as SOLine;
            if (orderLine == null) return;

            SOLineExt orderLineExt = orderLine.GetExtension<SOLineExt>();

            var product = Base.Products.Current;
            CROpportunityProductsExt productExt = product.GetExtension<CROpportunityProductsExt>();

            orderLineExt.UsrHasAnticipatedDiscount = productExt.UsrHasAnticipatedDiscount;
            orderLineExt.UsrAnticipatedDiscountPct = productExt.UsrAnticipatedDiscountPct;
            orderLineExt.UsrAnticipatedDiscountAmt = productExt.UsrAnticipatedDiscountAmt;
            orderLineExt.UsrAnticipatedUnitPrice = productExt.UsrAnticipatedUnitPrice;
            orderLineExt.UsrTotalAnticipatedDiscountAmt = productExt.UsrTotalAnticipatedDiscountAmt;
        });

        return baseMethod(adapter);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass line item custom field value to sales order from opportunity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42352177/how-to-pass-line-item-custom-field-value-to-sales-order-from-opportunity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two posts with answers to this same question:

[Populate custom field while creating sale order from opportunity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43921902/populate-custom-field-while-creating-sale-order-from-opportunity)

[How to pass custom field vales from Opportunity to sales Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36156112/how-to-pass-custom-field-vales-from-opportunity-to-sales-order)

To sum it up, you can add a rowinserting event handler within the button action or my preference is within DoCreateSalesOrder (extending OpportunityMaint) like the example below...

```
[PXOverride]
public virtual void DoCreateSalesOrder(OpportunityMaint.CreateSalesOrderFilter param, Action<OpportunityMaint.CreateSalesOrderFilter> del)
{
        PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<SOOrderEntry>(graph =>
        {
            graph.RowInserting.AddHandler<SOLine>((cache, args) =>
            {
                var soLine = (SOLine)args.Row;
                if (soLine == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                CROpportunityProducts opProduct = PXResult<CROpportunityProducts>.Current;
                if (opProduct == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                var opProductExt = PXCache<CROpportunityProducts>.GetExtension<CROpportunityProductsExt>(opProduct);
                var soLineExt = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(soLine);

                //Copy all extension fields here...

            });
        });

    del(param);
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks Brendan! I was searching for CRM quote... if I searched for opportunity that would have been better!

Comment: no problem. Sometimes just searching the graph name too would return some results if unsure which keyword to use. "OpportunityMaint" in this case would return questions related to opportunities.